# RxJS - Create Observable from an EventEmitter's multiple events

Tags: node.js, rxjs, observable, eventemitter, reactivex

I have a node.js EventEmitter which raises the following events: `error`, `message`.

Is there a straight forward way I can create an RxJS Observable from it?

i.e `next()` called on `message` and `error()` called on `error`.

Comment: `EventEmitter` is an Observable already. It inherits from `Subject` that inherits from `Observable` class.

Comment: I should have been more clear, it is a regular node.js event emitter. Changed question to reflect this.

Comment: @user3690467 Please notice that I had to edit my answer right now. The first option was actually wrong if the error events are sent manully.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create it like this:

```
const obs$ = Observable.create(observer => {
  emitter.on('message', val => observer.next(val));
  emitter.on('error', err => observer.error(err));
});
```

---

As an alternative, you can do this by constructinng and chaining observables like this, but it's clearly less readable:

```
const message$ = Observable.fromEvent(emitter, 'message');
const error$ = Observable.fromEvent(emitter, 'error');

const obs$ = Observable.merge(
  message$.catch(err => Observable.of(err)),
  error$.mergeMap(val => Observable.throw(val)),
);
```