# Type inference does not always work with MatSelect of Angular Material

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, type-inference

In an Angular component I have a child of type `MatSelect` which I can get hold of via the following code

```
@ViewChild('mySelect') mySelect: MatSelect;
```

I can now use `mySelect` in the code to react to changes in the selection, for instance like this

```
this.mySelect.selectionChange
.pipe(
  map(selChange => // here type inference finds that selChange is of type MatSelectChange
)
```

In this case type inference works fine.

My problem is that, if I change the code like in the following snippet, type inference seems not to work any more

```
of(null)
.pipe(
  switchMap(() => this.mySelect.selectionChange),
  map(selChange => // here type inference does not work and  selChange is of type {}
)
```

Any suggestion on why this different behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

**selectionChange** is not of type **Observable**.
It is an **EventEmitter**

**SwitchMap** returns **Observable**, so you can't return **EventEmitter**

*If you would like to bind data, you could use a simple output:*

```
<mat-select (selectionChange)="doSomething($event)" />
```

Or check out how to create an **Observable** from **EventEmitter**:

```
const obs$ = Observable.create(observer => {
  emitter.on('message', val => observer.next(val));
  emitter.on('error', err => observer.error(err));
});
```

(ref: [RxJS - Create Observable from an EventEmitter's multiple events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48621655/rxjs-create-observable-from-an-eventemitters-multiple-events))

Comment: Angular EventEmitter extends Subject which extends Observable. So EventEmitter is an Observable. In Node things are different. My question is not about how to use `selectionChange` of `MatSelect`. It is about type inference.